# Windows 10 Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 7, Windows 10 & Ubuntu 17.10.1 on the computer on 1 MBR HDD. Currently I can boot all of them. But I need to boot using the Windows boot manager. And I want to know if I can boot Ubuntu through the windows boot manager

I tried EasyBCD but I out dated

Answer (score 1):

EasyBCD doesn't support the windows 10 boot loader as you said. However it should be possible to add a entry manually to the with bcdedit as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries#adding-a-new-boot-entry-in-windows-vista-and-later).

A simpler solution might be to [install grub boot loader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) on your Ubuntu partition and choose grub as the primary boot loader in UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: First link does not describe *how* to add Ubuntu boot entry to Windows BCD.